# I Installed kubectl locally ,but when i try to used that utility getting error,

Tags: kubernetes

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get namespace
kubectl describe ns.yml
```

When I try to execute any commands from above I am getting the following error:

> E0824 14:41:42.499373   27188 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:53721/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:53721: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Could you please help me out, how to resolve it?

Can any one tell me what is wrong with my kubutcl utility

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That error message suggests to me that your `$HOME/.kube/config` file is configured to point at `http://127.0.0.1:53721` but there isn't a Kubernetes API server there.  This seems like a Kubernetes local client configuration problem, more than anything programming-related, and you might ask your local sysadmins the right way to configure that file.

Answer (score 1):

So, the kubectl commands needs to be configured! Currently kubectl is trying to connect to the kube-api on your local machine (127.0.0.1), clearly there is no kubernetes there so it throws the error "No connection could be made..."

To change the kubectl settings you need to find the kubectl config file at the path:

Windows: `%userprofile"\.kube\config`
Linux: `$HOME/.kube/config`

Open the file with any editor and then you need to change the ip 127.0.0.1 to any external ip of one of your nodes!

This will solve your connection problem but there might be another issue with your certificate! I will alter my answer when you tell me what kubernetes distro you are using (e.g. k3s, k8s, ...)